# Portuguese accentuation issue on newer versions of Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: keyboard

Recently I move from ubuntu 18.04 to 22.04 and I notice a change in keyboard's behaviour during accentuation. When type an character accent, like acute, the keyboard prints a pre-visualization from the accent like this:

[pre-visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LPsj.png)

Even though it is not particularly annoying, this behaviour breaks the typing flow in some programs, specially in whatsapp web, where the program removes the entire character after you type it in the begin of the sentence.

I didn't find anything related with this and not even mentions about when this was changed or why. Is there a way to disable it in order to this back to work as traditionally it did?